# Intel i915 Tearing issues

Tags: xorg, intel-graphics, tearing

I'm using FOSS intel graphics drivers with Kernel 3.8.0-29 and Kubuntu 13.04.  There seems to be video tear at the top of my screen.  It's apparent when I'm dragging windows around or playing video back in full screen.  I've been googling and apparently there's a tear free option that I can put into an xorg.conf file?  However, I do not have an xorg.conf file and I am not familiar with the syntax to set one up.

So this is really a 2 part question.  1) I'd like to try to xorg.conf option, so what would I need to put into the file to set it up?  2) If that's not the way to fix this, has anyone found a way to fix it?  I'm not looking to disable compositing, as it's just the top of the screen and I can sort of deal with it, but it's bumming me out.

Thanks.

Comment: which intel graphics driver you are using? is it `Xorg::lts-raring` version?

Comment: xserver-xorg-video-intel 2.21.6-0ubuntu4.1

Comment: I had the same problem.. But solved my issue.. I posted my answer.. Hope it works for you too.

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/418398