# Tear-free disabled in Intel Graphics, tearing in Xubuntu

Tags: 13.10, xubuntu, intel-graphics, intel, tearing

I use Xubuntu 13.10 and have installed the Intel Graphics Installer. I did it in order to reduce the amount of screen tearing with the VESA drivers earlier. 
But I see "tear free" as disabled, when I do:

```
cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log
```

I can see tear free is disabled. I'm putting in the line:

```
[  1718.525] (**) intel(0): "Tear free" disabled
```

How do I enable tear-free? I have the 945GM graphics driver.
Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

TearFree is disabled by default. To enable it create the directory,

```
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

Then add to the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option      "AccelMethod" "sna"
   Option      "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

I have run into this problem with xubuntu 16.04.2. Tear free stopped working.
In my case, for some reason the package `xserver-xorg-video-intel` was no longer installed. `Xorg.0.log` said the intel module was not loaded, and that instead the modesetting driver was loaded, and as great as that may be, the config file to set tear free was being ignored. Restoring the package fixed things, tear free worked again. I don't know if this is how it is supposed to be: the `xserver-xorg-video-intel`package description says its use on post 2007 hardware is discouraged, but horrible tearing graphics is much more discouraging.

The package in my case is actually `xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04`

Comment: Some people (https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/4cojj9/it_is_probably_time_to_ditch_xf86videointel/) are saying compton fixes all tearing. Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution presented by **bain** worked for me, but only after removing the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file.
A rename backs it up additionally, in case you want to restore it at some point.

`sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.back`

In my case, the file was automatically created by the nvidia driver and not needed by my system. It's unknown to me, why & what interfered with the intel device settings.