# Intel HD4600 screen tearing on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics, xorg.conf, amdgpu

I recently installed 17.04 on my desktop PC. Due to some technical constraints (I have a dual monitor setup and one them has only VGA adapter), I have to use both my RX480(primary monitor) and Intel HD4600.
While RX480 has no problems whatsoever, I am seeing blocky tears/tearing on my monitor on HD4600.

I tried the following:

[Tear-free disabled in Intel Graphics, tearing in Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418398/tear-free-disabled-in-intel-graphics-tearing-in-xubuntu)

https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2344312.html

http://www.apolitech.com/2016/01/how-to-solve-video-tearing-on-intel.html

But to make matters worse, after adding the *xorg.conf* to */etc/X11*

or alternatively *20-intel.conf* to */usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d*

with the parameters

> Section "Device"
>
> Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
>
> Driver      "intel"
>
> Option      "AccelMethod" "sna"
>
> Option      "TearFree" "true"
>
> EndSection

I was stuck with the message on boot:

> "/dev/sda1: clean, 121563/920272 files, 701079/3680256 blocks"

Adding GRUB parameter "nomodeset" disabled HD4600 and dropped the resolution on primary monitor to 800x600.

Am I doing something wrong? If not, what else I can do? Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `i915.enable_rc6=0` to your boot parameter.  This should fix the tearing.  But it will disable an important power management module resulting in excessive fan use.