# Display tearing & flickering, Amd R9 270x

Tags: 16.04, display, amd-graphics

Here is a video documenting the issue :
https://youtu.be/-5rbocJ3V-s

Hardware:

Gigabyte GA G31 ES2L v2.x

R9 270x

C2D e8400

4GB Ram

120GB SSD

Details window:

Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64 Bit

Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on AMD PITCAIRN (DRM 2.46.0/4.8.0-51-generic, LLVM 3.8.0)

Answer (score 0):

Do check to see if you can reproduce the isse with another cable Hdmi or display port.

On Graphic card is it DVI-I Dual-Link, DVI-D Dual Link, HDMI, or Display port.
On Screen is it DVI-I Dual-Link, DVI-D Dual Link, HDMI, or Display port.

I love DVI but they have an egregious tendency to bend pins and this transmits from male to female like an std so if you flip the cable over three times both screen and graphic card and both sides of the cable will all have the bent pins and openings where two pins try to fit in one opening.

it's sublte so it's hard to notice but it will cause this type of flickering quite exactly.

you can bend the plastic of the bent opening in the female back into shape and you can also bend the bent pin on the male back into position.

if the issue persists with other cables and ports it probably is a driver issue of sorts I'd recommend seeing if the issue exists with fedora 25 or other (windows if that's an option).

I'd have suggested the AMDPRO GPU driver but it looks like your graphics card isn't on the support list.

that's all i've got hope this helps.

Comment: I can confirm this is a software/driver issue. I do have windows 10 installed on this machine too and it has no such issues.

I also just installed Ubuntu 14 as I read a post on OMGUbuntu which cautioned Radeon users about staying away from Ubuntu 16.

It worked. I tested a few videos & games. After that I upgraded via terminal and restarted. I got a message to upgrade to 16.04 which I declined.

Than I got a popup from automatic updates that there were ~104mb of updates available, so I proceeded but after install it asked to restart and the problem is back. I am still on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: found this which may concern you : https://askubuntu.com/questions/913765/why-are-we-discouraged-to-use-xserver-xorg-video-intel-how-to-configure-tear-fr

do you have this driver enabled?

Comment: and this one : https://askubuntu.com/questions/418398/tear-free-disabled-in-intel-graphics-tearing-in-xubuntu

Comment: I had already tried the second method of enabling the tearfree mode. But it was pointless as when I use the list gpu command it would only show my AMD card.

Comment: what about removing the intel driver altogether?

Comment: another idea : https://askubuntu.com/a/890758/307184 try it and reboot see if that helps. if not undo the change.

Comment: It seems like there is an issue with Ubuntu's compatibility with r9 270x gpu's. I even installed the AMD GPU PRO and also the beta version. But the problem still continues. Went back to Ubuntu 14.04 for the time being and have disabled updates.

Comment: the amd gpu pro can't be loaded anyways since it doesn't support your GPU. dunno what to say I'm sorry man. does the problem persist in fedora or manjaro