# Why are we discouraged to use xserver-xorg-video-intel? How to configure tear free in intel modesetting driver?

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, intel-graphics

The package `xserver-xorg-video-intel` has a description which says "The use of this driver is discouraged if your hw is new enough (ca.
2007 and newer). You can try uninstalling this driver and let the
server use it's builtin modesetting driver instead." (the apostrophe grammar error is not mine).

So my hardware is a 2016 ThinkPad P50. Xubuntu 16.04.2.

However, when this package is not present, the Xserver log reports

```
   10.740] (II) LoadModule: "intel"
 [    10.740] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module intel
 [    10.740] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
 [    10.740] (II) Unloading intel
 [    10.740] (EE) Failed to load module "intel" (module does not exist,
```

and a configuration file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`is ignored. This file sets tear free = "true" and it doesn't work.
Restoring the apparently prehistoric module makes everything work again. The module is loaded, sna accelaration is set, tear free mode is enabled.

So the advice in the package description appears misleading (not 'seriously misleading' as I first posted).

But ... the failed load log continues,and the modesetting driver is loaded. It seems this is supposed to be a Good Thing. How come then the config file to turn on tear free doesn't do anything? I suppose I should search configuring modesetting drivers....

```
10.740] (II) UnloadModule: "intel"
 [    10.740] (II) Unloading intel
 [    10.740] (EE) Failed to load module "intel" (module does not exist, 0)
 [    10.740] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 0
 [    10.740] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
 [    10.740] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 2
 [    10.740] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
 [    10.740] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
 [    10.740] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
 [    10.740] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
 [    10.740]    compiled for 1.18.4, module version = 1.18.4
 [    10.740]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
 [    10.740]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 20.0
 [    10.740] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
 [    10.741] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
```

Comment: "seriously misleading." No it is not. It says "discouraged" not "avoid like the plague".  And do you have `xf86-video-intel` installed? That's where the 'intel' driver is that you need.

Comment: OK, maybe some hours of frustration caused me to over-react, although '2007'! Those were the days of Pentiums and Ubuntu had just released its first LTS.
 I don't have a package xf86-video-intel installed but it seems that the Ubuntu package xserver-xorg-video-intel is the same thing (the one that discourages us from using it).