# Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop glitch [Small green box over the screen]

Tags: keyboard, 20.04, .desktop, desktop-icons

[image: ubuntu 20.04 Desktop]

Hi, It's been 4 days I've installed ubuntu 20.04 on my Dell Inspiron 3567. After installation, my 1st boot went well (I can't type a keyboard while on desktop). But after that, in every boot, I had the issue above. I can't refresh the icons either via mouse or keyboard. It's so irritating.

Please help me fix this issue. 
Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

To temporarily fix it press`alt+f2` then `r`.

To actually fix the issue, run these commands in the terminal.

```
sudo apt remove --purge xorg xserver-xorg gnome-session ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-desktop gdm3 xwayland
sudo autoremove --purge
sudo apt install gnome-session ubuntu-desktop-minimal
reboot
```

Read [this](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+question/689506) for more information.

Comment: `sudo apt autoremove --purge`, not `sudo autoremove --purge`? Just a mistype by mjglopez in the linked post, I think. PS: alt-f2 + r works for me, but the re-installing steps do not. Still troubleshooting.

Comment: `alt+f2` and `r` worked fine.

I'm afraid about `sudo apt remove --purge xorg xserver-xorg gnome-session ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-desktop gdm3 xwayland` as it removes lots of packages, as you can see the screenshot below.
[https://i.imgur.com/Bj15oDO.png](https://i.imgur.com/Bj15oDO.png)

Can you please tell me what does the above code does?

However, I managed to hide issue simply by logging out and logging in to `Wayland`.

Please let me know if I did anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` and its contents (`20-intel.conf`), then rebooted, and that seems to have done the trick. I don't completely understand but it seems having that file (`20-intel.conf`) present, causes an old Intel package/driver (`xserver-xorg-video-intel`) to be loaded, instead of using the (recommended?) modesetting driver; check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/913765/why-are-we-discouraged-to-use-xserver-xorg-video-intel-how-to-configure-tear-fr) for more info. After rebooting, you can check what changed by comparing `Xorg.0.log` and `Xorg.0.log.old` in `~/.local/share/xorg` (or wherever your Xorg logs are located). You should notice new entries with `modeset(0):` instead of `intel(0):`.

Now, I originally created that conf file to solve tearing issues on 19.04 (which got solved then but still had the occasional coloured glitches on Firefox). Hopefully, they won't return.

**PS**: Worth mentioning that before deleting said folder, I'd already tried the package purge and reinstall, recommended in the other answer, which didn't work. So if deleting the Xorg conf doesn't work for you, you may also want to try that purge and reinstall as well.

Comment: Yes, now I remembered that I had a screen tearing while watching the video in full screen. I had to create a file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` to fix the problem. After the reboot, then I was faced with a green mess.

Comment: @RajeshChaudhary Yeah, same here. I haven't noticed the tearing so far, after deleting, so it's possible the modesetting driver in 20.04 has fixed that. Does this solution work for you?

Comment: Ah, Partially if I've to say. The glitch issue seems to be fixed but again screen tearing issue arose. What is your opinion on Wayland as both issue seems to be fine there?

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. I don't know a lot about Wayland, haven't used it before myself so no real opinions on it. Though if I still had the tearing issue, I think I'd still prefer to fix the "main" boot option, rather than resort to Wayland. If you haven't tried this already, you could try disabling PSR by creating a file named `i915.conf` in folder `/etc/modprobe.d` and enter into the file: `options i915 enable_psr=0`. Save and reboot as usual.

Comment: Is it going to affect any other place except for screen tearing?

Comment: @RajeshChaudhary It's only for screen tearing. It disables Panel Self Refresh (PSR) which linux drivers seem unable to cope with, causing tearing. You can google and find out more, to be sure.

Comment: Unfortunately, disabling PSR is also not working.

Comment: But it gets automatically fixed. I mean to say I had the issue with the gnome-video-player with full screen; I switched to VLC & now no more tearing.

Comment: @RajeshChaudhary Ah, okay, I rarely use that player. I think back then, I first noticed the tearing on Youtube. So far, I still haven't noticed any tearing, even the occasional colour glitches are gone, hopefully for good.