# Screen tearing in Xfce/Compiz, not in Unity/Compiz

Tags: xubuntu, compiz, opengl, tearing

I would like to use Xubuntu with Compiz on my old Thinkpad T60 with Intel Core 2 Duo integrated graphics. The installation works and the performance is fine, however I get heavy screen tearing e.g. while scrolling websites, playing videos or moving windows.

Just for comparison, I started a Vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 Live ISO and immediately, there was no screen tearing at all without altering any settings, so the hardware seems to be capable of displaying everything without teating. However, I would still like to stay with Xubuntu.

I also installed the Compizconfig Settings Manager on the Ubuntu Live installation to compare the settings, but could not find a clue on what the difference is that makes my Xubuntu/Compiz installation cause to tear.

Is there a solution to this or things to try out?

Edit: I have no tearing problems with Xfce4 & Compiz at this point. I don't know what exactly the problem was, however, I re-installed Xubuntu 16.04.2 again, because I was setting up different parts of the system and had made some mistakes.

After the clean installation, I first followed this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/469653/351726 to enable the Intel driver's VSync/TearFree features.

After that, I disabled the Xfce compositor and directly installed and set up Compiz according to this routine: https://askubuntu.com/a/703509/351726

After doing so, I experienced no further tearing with dragging windows, scrolling websites or playing videos (fullscreen). Maybe I made mistakes while setting up Compiz previously or the Compton-installation was interfering with it.

If you have similar issues, try a clean install with this workflow.